# Bluetooth profile info in linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, embedded-linux, bluetooth-lowenergy

As bluetooth device has a number of **bluetooth profiles**. when want to do communication is bluetooth device, first pair bluetooth device and then starts sending data using bluetooth.

In linux, hcitool is used to scan nearby bluetooth devices.

Questions:
1)  How can i know which bluetooth profile is supported by selected nearby bluetooth device?**Is there any particular command to know bluetooth profile supported by selected nearby bluetooth device in linux?**

2) suppose, i come to know selected nearby bluetooth device support abcd and xyz bluetooth profiles. **How can i select particular bluetooth profile in linux?**, example abcd out of supported profiles.

2) **How can i connect to that selected bluetooth device as SPP profile for transferring data as serial port in linux?**

Regards,
Sukhdeep Singh

Comment: this is tagged as 'bluetooth-lowenergy', but there is no concept of "profiles" in low energy...  is this just tagged wrong?

Comment: Are you sure? https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BLE.aspx https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/PXP.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In linux, sdptool utility is provided with which you can search your own device supported profiles and other devices supported profiles(sdptool browse local/).
2. Since you know the peer device support abcd/xyz profile, you dont have to select any profile, you have to intiate a profile level connection request(pairing/authentication also needs to be taken care)
3. For SPP connection, rfcomm tool is provided by bluez

Comment: Thanks, Suppose in Linux system, i have two bluetooth device. In one bluetooth, i can add service using **sdptool add service**. But in second bluetooth device, how can i add particular service.

Comment: Do accept the answer incase you think it worked for you!!! try to add using sdptool hciX add service